Update issues from 22.04.4/5 to 24.04.1
I tried several times to upgrade both from 22.04.4 and now from 22.04.5 to 24.04.1. On two computers the update went fine, on my desktop I've just struggled.
When using GUI, updates brakes, and have to fix it 4-5 times with apt --fix-broken install; then I have after a GUI, but nothing else beyond a mouse cursor. When updating from console, the update is completed, but no network, no GUI login screen (I use sddm).
Actuall, my only question is when do you guys think there will be an update without issues. As I can see, I'm not the only one with these issues.

This question is similar to: Major software missing after 24.04.1 LTS upgrade. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
